# Were women allowed to attend the annual feasts?

Tags: exodus, 1-samuel

1 Samuel 1 (KJV)

> Now there was a certain man of Ramathaimzophim, of mount Ephraim, and his name was Elkanah, the son of Jeroham, the son of Elihu, the son of Tohu, the son of Zuph, an Ephrathite:  2 And he had two wives;  the name of the one was Hannah, and the name of the other Peninnah:  and Peninnah had children, but Hannah had no children.   3 And this man went up out of his city yearly to worship and to sacrifice unto the LORD of hosts in Shiloh.   And the two sons of Eli, Hophni and Phinehas, the priests of the LORD, were there.   4 **And when the time was that Elkanah offered, he gave to Peninnah his wife, and to all her sons and her daughters, portions:  5 But unto Hannah he gave a worthy portion;  for he loved Hannah:  but the LORD had shut up her womb**

Exodus 23:17 (KJV)

> 17 Three times in the year all thy males shall appear before the Lord GOD.

According to Exodus only males were allowed to appear before the Lord in the annual feasts,so how can we understand the above text?

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <sup>8</sup> Ye shall not do after all the things that we do here this day, every man whatsoever is right in his own eyes. <sup>9</sup> For ye are not as yet come to the rest and to the inheritance, which the LORD your God giveth you.
> <sup>10</sup> But when ye go over Jordan, and dwell in the land which the LORD your God giveth you to inherit, and when he giveth you rest from all your enemies round about, so that ye dwell in safety; <sup>11</sup> Then there shall be a place which the LORD your God shall choose to cause his name to dwell there; thither shall ye bring all that I command you; your burnt offerings, and your sacrifices, your tithes, and the heave offering of your hand, and all your choice vows which ye vow unto the LORD: <sup>12</sup> **And ye shall rejoice before the LORD your God, ye, and your sons, and your daughters, and your menservants, and your maidservants, and the Levite that is within your gates**; forasmuch as he hath no part nor inheritance with you.
> <sup>13</sup> Take heed to thyself that thou offer not thy burnt offerings in every place that thou seest: <sup>14</sup> But in the place which the LORD shall choose in one of thy tribes, there thou shalt offer thy burnt offerings, and there thou shalt do all that I command thee.
> ...
> <sup>17</sup> Thou mayest not eat within thy gates the tithe of thy corn, or of thy wine, or of thy oil, or the firstlings of thy herds or of thy flock, nor any of thy vows which thou vowest, nor thy freewill offerings, or heave offering of thine hand: <sup>14</sup> But thou must eat them before the LORD thy God in the place which the LORD thy God shall choose, **thou, and thy son, and thy daughter, and thy manservant, and thy maidservant, and the Levite that is within thy gates: and thou shalt rejoice before the LORD thy God in all that thou puttest thine hands unto.**
> -- Deuteronomy 12:8-14,17-18 (KJV)

It was mandatory to take ALL sacrifices to the "*place which the LORD your God shall choose to cause his name to dwell there*", and the invitation to attend such events as required sacrifice, was extended to every man, woman and child (servant or free) so the entire nation, together, might "*rejoice before the LORD your God*".

In the absence of a specific instruction to exclude anyone from the annual feasts, this general instruction must hold precedence.

#### Additional Comment

In regard to Exodus 23:17, Deuteronomy says:

> <sup>16</sup> Three times in a year shall all thy males appear before the LORD thy God in the place which he shall choose; in the feast of unleavened bread, and in the feast of weeks, and in the feast of tabernacles: and they shall not appear before the LORD empty: <sup>17</sup> Every man shall give as he is able, according to the blessing of the LORD thy God which he hath given thee.
> -- Deuteronomy 16:16-17 (KJV)

However, in the verses immediately prior, we have this:

> <sup>10</sup> And thou shalt keep the feast of weeks unto the LORD thy God with a tribute of a freewill offering of thine hand, which thou shalt give unto the LORD thy God, according as the LORD thy God hath blessed thee: <sup>11</sup> And thou shalt rejoice before the LORD thy God, **thou, and thy son, and thy daughter, and thy manservant, and thy maidservant, and the Levite that is within thy gates, and the stranger, and the fatherless, and the widow, that are among you**, in the place which the LORD thy God hath chosen to place his name there.
> ...
> <sup>13</sup> Thou shalt observe the feast of tabernacles seven days, after that thou hast gathered in thy corn and thy wine: <sup>14</sup> And thou shalt rejoice in thy feast, **thou, and thy son, and thy daughter, and thy manservant, and thy maidservant, and the Levite, the stranger, and the fatherless, and the widow, that are within thy gates.**
> -- Deuteronomy 16:10-11,13-14 (KJV)

Clearly, the feasts were built into the governance of the nation of Israel for the express purpose of giving every citizen, regardless of situation, the opportunity to rejoice before the LORD their God.

Answer (score 7):

**OP** (bold added):

> > Exod 23: 17 Three times in the year all thy males shall appear before the Lord GOD.
>
> According to Exodus **only males were allowed** to appear before the Lord in the annual feasts,so how can we understand the above text?

No, [Exodus 23:17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+23%3A14-17&version=NIV;WLC) does not delimit attendance at [festivals](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/festivals) to "your males" (זְכוּרְךָ) -- rather, it explicitly lays on males an obligation of thrice-yearly festival attendance that it does not lay on females. I.e., it does *not* say: "...and thy females shall not come but shall rather stay at home".

The optional attendance by women is well illustrated by the story of Hannah in 1 Samuel 1, noted by OP.

There are a number of texts showing (in fact, depending on) the attendance of women at the so-called "pilgrimage" festivals, the most notorious being [Judges 21:19-25](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges+21%3A19-25&version=NIV;WLC).

OP's question rests on a false premise.